# datetime() in SQLite Manager

Tags: datetime, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I cannot seem to figure out why datetime does not work for me on some data I imported from CSV. I have a column, TIMESTAMP, which is of type datetime.

Select TIMESTAMP from GPS limit 1 <-This gives me a time, "6/29/2009 00:00:00"
Select datetime(TIMESTAMP) from GPS limit 1 <- This gives me a pink field in SQLite manager, which seems empty.
Select datetime('now') from GPS limit 1 <- This gives me the current date and time. ("2012-12-19 20:45:17") It is formatted differently than my other data - is there a datatype issue?

What is going on? Did my "Timestamp" data not actually get converted into a DATETIME object? Why is it stored as text? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have a native date/time type; dates are stored either as numbers or as strings.

To be understood by SQLite's built-in [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), date strings must have a format like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.